# Why is my background videos not changing?

Tags: javascript, foreach, navbar, addition, addeventlistener

I'm making video slider background but my Javascript for video slider navigation doesn't work (when i click on the buttons, the first video doesn't change to another videos). I don't see any mistake on the console tho. I don't know what's wrong...anybody knows please help me! Thạnk you so much!
This is my code:

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    }

    header {
        z-index: 999;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 15px 200px;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
    }

    header .brand {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    header .navigation {
        position: relative;
    }

    header .navigation .navigation-items a {
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-left: 30px;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }

    header .navigation .navigation-items a:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background: #fff;
        width: 0;
        height: 3px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }

    header .navigation .navigation-items a:hover:before {
        width: 100%;
    }

    section {
        padding: 100px 200px;
    }

    .home {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: #ED2CC4;
    }

    .home:before {
        z-index: 777;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(3, 96, 251, 0.3);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .home .content {
        z-index: 888;
        color: #fff;
        width: 70%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: none;
    }

    .home .content.active {
        display: block;
    }

    .home .content h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
        font-weight: 900;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        line-height: 75px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .home .content h1 span {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .home .content p {
        margin-bottom: 65px;
    }

    .home .content a {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 15px 35px;
        color: #1680AC;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .home .media-icons {
        z-index: 888;
        position: absolute;
        right: 30px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
    }

    .home .media-icons a {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }

    .home .media-icons a:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .home .media-icons a:hover {
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }

    .home video {
        z-index: 000;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .slider-navigation {
        z-index: 888;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transform: translateY(80px);
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    .slider-navigation .nav-btn {
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }

    .slider-navigation .nav-btn.active {
        background: #2696E9;
    }

    .slider-navigation .nav-btn:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .slider-navigation .nav-btn:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    .video-slide {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
    }

    .video-slide.active {
        clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
        transition: 2s ease;
        transition-property: clip-path;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1040px) {
        header {
            padding: 12px 20px;
        }

        section {
            padding: 100px 20px;
        }

        .home .media-icons {
            right: 15px;
        }

        header .navigation {
            display: none;
        }

        header .navigation.active {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
        }

        header .navigation .navigation-items a {
            color: #222;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        header .navigation .navigation-items a:before {
            background: #222;
            height: 5px;
        }

        header .navigation.active .navigation-items {
            background: #fff;
            width: 600px;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 40px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(1 1 1 / 20%);
        }

        .menu-btn {
            background: url(menu.png)no-repeat;
            background-size: 30px;
            background-position: center;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s ease;
        }

        .menu-btn.active {
            z-index: 999;
            background: url(close.png)no-repeat;
            background-size: 25px;
            background-position: center;
            transition: 0.3s ease;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 560px) {
        .home .content h1 {
            font-size: 3em;
            line-height: 60px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Website Landing Page - With Background Video Slider | Travel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="brand">Travel</a>
        <div class="menu-btn "></div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="navigation-items">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Explore</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="home">
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid3.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid2.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid1.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid4.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>

        <div class="content active">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Camping.<br><span>Enjoy</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Adventures.<br><span>Off Road</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Road Trip.<br><span>Together</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Feel Nature.<br><span>Relax</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-navigation">
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn')
        const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation')

        menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            menuBtn.classList.toggle('active')
            navigation.classList.toggle('active')
        })
        ////Javacript for video slider navigation
        const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-btn')
        const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.video-slide')

        var sliderNav = function(manual) {
            btns.forEach((btn) => {
                btn.classList.remove('active')
            })
            slides.forEach((slide) => {
                slide.classList.remove('active')
            })

            btns[manual].classList.add("active")
            slides[manual].classList.add("active")
        }

        btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                sliderNav(i)
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<video class="video-slide ⏩active⏪" src="vid3.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
<video class="video-slide" src="vid2.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
<video class="video-slide" src="vid1.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
<video class="video-slide" src="vid4.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
```

try by adding an "active" class in one of any above video tags so the script can change that class to another because, for the first time, it's looking for an active class if it works like bootstrap counsel.